# Errors Enum - common parameters for cases

Tags: swift, error-handling

I have got sample Error enum in my application:

```
public enum APIError: Error {
    case IncorrectArguments(message: String)
    case MissingArgument(message: String)
}
```

And error handling looks like:

```
do {
    return try next.respond(to: request)
} catch let error as APIError {
    throw Abort(.badRequest, reason: error.message)
}
```

But I get compilation error in here saying: `Value of type 'APIError' has no member 'message'`.

I know I can get parameters by pattern matching, but I don't want to handle every case in exactly same way:

```
do {
    return try next.respond(to: request)
} catch APIError.MissingArgument(let message) {
    throw Abort(.badRequest, reason: message)
} catch APIError.IncorrectArguments(let message) {
    throw Abort(.badRequest, reason: message)
}
```

In future there may be more APIErrors in enum and I don't want to handle each one using separate catch block, because everyone will be exactly the same.

Is there any way to handle these errors in some generic way?

Comment: You are throwing errors in catch. You'd want to throw error in a function and catch it in a `Do..Catch`

Comment: `throw Abort` is Vapor way to return response with given status and message.

Comment: @Blejwi check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define computed properties on an enum like so:

```
public enum APIError: Error {
    case IncorrectArguments(message: String)
    case MissingArgument(message: String)

    var message: String {
        switch self {
            case .IncorrectArguments(let message): return message
            case .MissingArgument(let message): return message
        }
    }
}
```

And call the message computed properties from your catch clouser like this:

```
do {
    return try next.respond(to: request)
} catch let error as APIError {
    throw Abort(.badRequest, reason: error.message)
}
```